# jQuery use of clipboard for making class or id

Tags: jquery, copy, clipboard

So this is a bit abstract, but I'm trying to figure out if I can copy ID from some element and then use it on the another page? I know that in theory that's not possible, but the abstract part I had in mine is to maybe copy that ID as a text, so you would have it in clipboard and then on the next page use that text to form ID click?

To be more specific, let's say we have a list.
I will send jQuery to find `.item.active` element from this list and would want to copy that ID as a text to clipboard:

```
<ul>
<li class="item" id="first"> </li>
<li class="item" id="second"> </li>
<li class="item active" id="third"> </li>
</ul>
```

So in this case, copied text will be **third**.

Then on the next page I would like to create something like `$( "#third" ).trigger( "click" );`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use localStorage instead of your clipboard.

```
var third =  $("#third").attr("id");
localStorage.setItem("examplekey", third);
```

To retrieve it you just do:

```
  var secondpageThird = localStorage.getItem("examplekey");
```

Again  the conventional way would be to let the browser store the information, not your clipboard.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of localStorage, I will try it!